# Data binding stops when adding default value to field in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am re-asking the question because I left out vital info previously.

I have a date model which changes the values of an input based on this: [AngularJS: How to set default value to ng-model="searchText"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481366/angularjs-how-to-set-default-value-to-ng-model-searchtext).

```
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:20px;">
                        <h3 style="float:left;">Set All Dates: </h3>
                            <span style="padding-top:15px; padding-left:7px;" class="input-group date">
                                <input id="setAllEffectiveDates" type="text" data-ng-model="date" value="" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                            </span>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody data-ng-repeat="(associatedContract,ndc) in ndcs">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-group date updateIt">
                                        <input id="effectiveDate" type="text" data-ng-model="date" class="form-control input-sm">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

The above works as intended, when I select a date all of the inputs change to that selected date.

My problem is that I want to add a default value to the fields. This value is a variable that is being iterated through here: `<tbody data-ng-repeat="(associatedContract,ndc) in ndcs">`.

```
<input id="effectiveDate" type="text" data-ng-model="date" ng-init="date=ndc.value" class="form-control input-sm">
```

Adding `ng-init="date=ndc.value"` does add a default value coming from the controller as expected. But it removes the data binding. The field no longer updates when changing the the `input id="setAllEffectiveDates"`.

How can I have the default values but also have the data binding working?

edit:

updated function I added ng-change:

`<input id="setAllEffectiveDates" ng-change="updateEffectiveDates(date)" type="text" data-ng-model="date" value="" class="form-control input-sm">`

and then made a function:

```
    $scope.updateEffectiveDates = function (date) {
        angular.forEach($scope.ndcs, function (ndc) {
            ndc.value = date;
        });
        console.log($scope.ndcs);
    };
```

THis looks like it updates the model but not the fields on the page.

Comment: ng-init is used to call a function that you want to execute when the item is instantiated. The general recommendation is never to use it for anything. Can you initialize the model to the desired value in your controller?

Comment: @MikeFeltman Yes, but there are multiple date values which is why there is the ng-repeat. Are you saying pass in an array or something?

Comment: There's only one date in your model. Do you mean to use a date property that's available on the associatedContract or ndc objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `ng-init` is creating a new `date` variable on each new scope created by `ng-repeat`, so it won't be binding from your controller anymore. If you only need one date, try setting it to an object that exists in your controller:

Controller:

```
$scope.obj = {
    date: null
};
```

View:

```
<input ng-init="obj.date=ndc.value">
```

**Edit:** Just bind to the date that you already have on each array element:

`data-ng-model="ndc.date" ng-change="setOtherDates()"`

Final answer:

```
<input id="setAllEffectiveDates" ng-change="updateEffectiveDates(date)" type="text" data-ng-model="date" value="" class="form-control input-sm">
```

then:

```
<input id="effectiveDate" type="text" data-ng-model="ndc.value" class="form-control input-sm">
```

with function:

```
    $scope.updateEffectiveDates = function (date) {
        angular.forEach($scope.ndcs, function (ndc) {
            ndc.value = date;
        });
        console.log($scope.ndcs);
    };
```

Comment: This re-enables the data-binding but it sets all of the default incoming values to 1 particular value as well. There are multiple coming in on the ng-repeat.

Comment: Maybe you need to do: `data-ng-model="ndc.date" ng-init="ndc.date=ndc.value"`

Comment: Ok, so if I use the above. How will I change all ndc.date values within the ng-update after? Would I set the selector fields model to ndc.date also? Even though it's outside ng-repeat?  `<input id="setAllEffectiveDates" type="text" data-ng-model="date" value="" class="form-control input-sm">`

Comment: If each item in the array needs its own date, you can run a function using `ng-change`. So when the date changes, set the other dates.

Comment: You would set all of the dates in the model during this function?

Comment: Do I understand correctly - your initial `ng-repeat` contains objects with default dates. But then after the user changes the date, you need to change all other dates to that new date?

Comment: Correct, the initial ng-repeat contains objects with default dates. These date vary and come from a database. When the user changes the date of `<input id="setAllEffectiveDates">` all dates get changed.

Comment: You should point `ng-model` to `ndc.date`, and maybe you can forget about `ng-init`.

Comment: You mean the ng-model for #setAllEffectiveDates? It's out od the ng-repeate is that ok?

Comment: Basically, each element in the array needs its own date, since they start with a default date. If at any point all of those dates need to change, iterate over each item in your controller and change the date manually.

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer. Note that `$scope.updateEffectiveDates` may not need to take `date` as a parameter, since `ng-change` runs once `date` has been updated in the controller. So `$scope.date` should already be updated.

Comment: @DavidTunnell I re-read your comments and I apologize for being so dense. I kept missing your reference to `setAllEffectiveDates` and didn't see it in the HTML, but you were quite clear in what you were asking.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help.